# Hyperbolic functions simplifying

Tags: hyperbolic-functions

How do you simplify

$$\cosh(\sinh^{-1}(x))$$

to become

$$(1+x^2)^{1/2}$$

I have managed to get $(1+\sinh^2(\sinh^{-1}(x))^{1/2}$ but haven't been able to progress from there.

Comment: $$\sinh^2 (\sinh^{-1} x) = x^2 $$

Answer (score 2):

From $$\cosh^2t-\sinh^2t=1,$$ draw

$$\cosh t=\sqrt{1+\sinh^2t}$$ and set $$t=\sinh^{-1}x.$$

Answer (score 0):

By definition you have
$$cosh(x)=\frac{e^x+e^{-x}}{2}$$
and
$$ sinh(x)=\frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{2}$$
You can compute the inverse function and find
$$sinh^{-1}(x)=ln(x+\sqrt{x^2+1})$$
Which substituted in your expression gives
$$\frac{ e^{ln{(x+\sqrt{x^2+1})}}+e^{-ln(x+\sqrt{x^2+1})}}{2}$$

Now remember that logarithm is the inverse of exponential, notice that $\frac{1}{a+b}=\frac{1}{a+b}\cdot \frac{a-b}{a-b}$ and $-log(x)=log(\frac{1}{x})$. Your result will follow.

Answer (score 0):

Since Tavish has already given the crucial key in a comment, I just add another way using the differentiation rule for inverse functions:

Set $$f(x) = \cosh(\sinh^{-1}x)$$

Then
$$f'(x) = \frac x{f(x)} \Rightarrow \left([f(x)]^2\right)' = 2x$$

Hence,

$$[f(x)]^2 = x^2+c \stackrel{f>0, f(0)=1}{\Longrightarrow}f(x) =\sqrt{x^2+1}$$